On the calculation of $ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin{(2n+1)t}}{\sin{t}} dt $
I would like to help a friend who is stuck on this exercise. We are asked to prove that
$$
\forall n \geq 1, \frac{2}{\pi} \ln(1+n)\leq \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left|\frac{\sin{(2n+1)t}}{\sin{t}}\right| dt \leq \frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2}\ln(2n + 1)
$$
and to deduce that
$$
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin{(2n+1)t}}{\sin{t}} dt = \frac{\pi}{2}.
$$
The first question  is not a problem for me and for a second question i can directly prove that
$$
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin{(2n+1)t}}{\sin{t}} dt = \frac{\pi}{2}
$$
but I can't deduce it using the first question.

Do you mean the first inequality? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel

I can prove both inequalities; my question is how to calculate the integral using these two inequalities, which is the objective of the question

We can’t evaluate the integral using the two inequalities. Instead, we could use the identity:
$$\sin (2 k+1) t-\sin (2 k-1) t=2 \sin t \cos (2 k t), $$
adding them up from $k=1$ to $n$ and then divide by $\sin t$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \sum_{k=1}^n[\sin (2 k+1) t-\sin (2 k-1) t]=2 \sum_{k=1}^n \sin t \cos (2 k t) \\
\Rightarrow \quad  &\sin (2 n+1) t-\sin t=2 \sum_{k=1}^n \sin t \cos (2 k t)\\ \Rightarrow \quad  & \frac{\sin (2 n+1) t}{\sin t}-1=2 \sum_{k=1}^n \cos (2 k t)
\end{aligned}
$$
Integrating from $t=0$ to $\frac\pi 2$ gives
$$\boxed{\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\frac{\sin (2 n+1) t}{\sin t} = \frac\pi 2 }$$
where $n\in \mathbb N.$
Wish it helps!

That's not what I want. My idea was, by considering the sequence $ u_n = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin (2n+1)t}{\sin t} , dt $, to prove $ u_n = u_{n+1} $ by contradiction. If there exists an $ n $ such that $ u_n \neq u_{n+1} $, how can we reach a contradiction using the two inequalities? One can, through an integral calculation, start from $ u_{n+1} $ to arrive at $ u_n $, but that is not the goal.
